# Changing variable name (numbering) or adding numbers to a variable in asc order to assign values

Tags: php, arrays, variables, variable-assignment

How to change the variable name numbering in ascending order to assign values to them. 
eg: car_1, car_2, car_3, car_4........ so on..
my coding is something like;

```
for (i=1; i<20;i++){
$var[i] = $_POST["car_"i];
}

foreach ......so on........

echo $var[12]."<br/>";
```

I need a way to increase the number of 'car_' to assign each car value to the '$var' array. I have tried to add it like this:

```
$var[i] = $_POST["car_"&i];
```

AND

```
$var[i] = $_POST["car_"i""];
```

and none of these work. I would very much appreciate your help to solve this.

Comment: Your counting i is also a variable... so it's `$i` everytime you use it...

Comment: How can you do this in ASP classic??

Comment: Are you using PHP or ASP ? One must choose his language...

Comment: Im using both of them.

Comment: ASP & PHP in the same bit of code?  How?  Possibly this should be two separate questions, one for each language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to append strings then do this:

```
for ($i=1; $i<20;$i++) {
   $var[$i] = $_POST["car_".$i];
}
```

Comment: How can you do this in asp classic??

Comment: I'm not so familiar with asp but I think you can create `Dim var(20)` and then the post will be `request.querystring("car_"& i)`. So if you change my code it would be: `var(i) = request.querystring("car_"&i)`. (Notice: I didn't try it so not sure it's working:(  )

Comment: See [ASP - Changing variable name (numbering) or adding numbers to a variable in asc order to assign values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36599409/692942)