# ASP - Changing variable name (numbering) or adding numbers to a variable in asc order to assign values

Tags: variables, vbscript, asp-classic

How to change the variable name numbering in ascending order to assign values to them. eg: car_1, car_2, car_3, car_4........ so on.. my coding is something like;

```
for i=1 to 20
var(i) = request.form("car_"i)
next

foreach ......so on........

response.write(var(12) & "<br/>")
```

I need a way to increase the number of 'car_' to assign each car value to the 'var' array. I have tried to add it like this:

```
var(i) = request.form("car_"&i)
```

AND

```
var(i) = request.form("car_"i"")
```

and none of these work. I would very much appreciate your help to solve this.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET or ASP Classic?  Which programming language?  The code and tags are all over the place so it's not clear what's going on here.  As for "numbering your variables", isn't that what arrays are for?  From the looks of the code it sounds like what you need is some introductory tutorials on the basic syntax of whatever language you're using.

Comment: Im using Asp classic. Sorry for confusing with tags.

Comment: "car_"+i is not working ?

Comment: no. I tried that did not work.

Comment: @DnoreGen: What is the actual *exact* code you used and in what *specific* way did it fail?

Comment: this is the part where im stuck at. everything else works fine. And array has () brackets not square [].

Comment: and does "car_" & CStr(i) works ?

Comment: @DnoreGen: If this is the actual code you're using then you should really start with an introductory tutorial on ASP Classic and VB Script.  This code isn't even syntactically correct.  This isn't how arrays are used in VB Script, string concatenation needs an operator between the two string values, etc.

Comment: no. it does not work.

Comment: Do you have an error message ?

Comment: @David you are not really helpful.

Comment: no it just doesnt return a result. nothing is displayed when called

Comment: @DnoreGen: Maybe you can be more specific than "it doesn't work"?  Try to understand that we can't see your screen from here.  But honestly, you really should walk through some introductory tutorials in a language/technology/etc. when attempting to use it.  Focusing specifically on the problem at hand though, exactly *how* is it failing?  Can you provide a small yet complete example of *exactly* what you're attempting?  There could be context just outside of these one or two lines of code which would help.

Comment: @DnoreGen: Getting frustrated and trying to insult the people who are here to help you doesn't really solve the problem at hand.  Some debugging might, though.  For example, what is actually in the form data being sent to this page?  What is the specific line of code you're using to try to read that form data?  There are a number of attempts present in the question and in comments, which one are you currently using and in what way does it fail?  When you debug it, what are the exact runtime values/behavior you're seeing?  You have to help us to help you.

Comment: @DnoreGen It looks like you are possibly using JScript *(Microsoft implementation of  ECMAScript)* inside your Classic ASP pages, but from that limited example it's hard to tell I can see references to `&` for concatenation which is VBScript but then you use `foreach` which is JScript syntax, can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @DnoreGen How did you get on did any of the suggests help?

Comment: Yes you have answered my question. But I did figured it out before that. Thank you @Lankymart !! and others who actually helped.

Comment: @DnoreGen glad you found the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example isn't very clear ideally it could be better but the more I look at it the more I think you are using VBScript, so I'm going to try an interpret what you are trying to do.

```vb
Dim i
Dim min_i: min_i = 1
Dim max_i: max_i = 20
Dim vars(max_i)

For i = min_i To max_i
  vars(i) = Request.Form("car_" & i)
Next
'Returns the value of Request.Form("car_12")
Call Response.Write(vars(12) & "<br />")
```

The approach was sound you just needed to concatenate (`&`) the value of `i` on to the name of the `Request.Forms` value.

---

It's worth pointing out that this is no different to what [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328193/david) suggests in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36604600/692942) except that this example tries to stay as close to the original requirement as possible by outputting the values to an `Array` instead of directly to the response buffer.

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate values in VBScript with the `&` operator.  Such as:

```
"car_" & i
```

To demonstrate, go ahead and run this code in something like [this online code editor](http://www.landofcode.com/online-code-editor.php) (IE only, I suspect):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/vbscript">
            For i = 1 To 20
                document.write "car_" & i
                document.write "<br />"
            Next
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Which produces the following output:

```
car_1
car_2
car_3
car_4
car_5
car_6
car_7
car_8
car_9
car_10
car_11
car_12
car_13
car_14
car_15
car_16
car_17
car_18
car_19
car_20
```

The same also works in server-side VBScript:

```
<body>
    <% For i = 1 To 20 %>
        Car_<%=i%><br />
    <% Next %>
</body>
```

Which produces the same output.

Comment: This is for VBScript. I need it for asp classic. This doesnt work.

Comment: @DnoreGen: VBScript is the language used in ASP Classic.  What other language are you using and how did you manage to do that?  If you're using some 3rd party ASP components in order to use a non-VBScript language then the problem could be in that.

Comment: @David Classic ASP supports VBScript and JScript out of the box with other Active Scripting languages also being available to download from 3rd parties.

Comment: @Lankymart: Fair enough, though the OP's last comment still makes no sense.  I suspect they're somewhat confused about the technologies being used here, and not knowing which language they're using is definitely going to lead to syntax problems.

Comment: I think you are right with VBScript they're just not explaining it well. Plus they have [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36597999/692942)... :O